# Calling methods java

Tags: java, methods, enums

I have a enum and every enum must have specific fields, such as price, which will not be modified, and I want to create a class to get this fields, what can I do in this situation? How can I call the class using the enums or what can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
public enum SalaryHeadMasterEnum {

    BASIC_PAY("basic pay"),
    MEDICAL_ALLOWANCE("Medical Allowance");

    private String name;

    private SalaryHeadMasterEnum(String stringVal) {
        name=stringVal;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

    public static String getEnumByString(String code){
        for(SalaryHeadMasterEnum e : SalaryHeadMasterEnum.values()){
            if(e.name.equals(code)) return e.name();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you can use below code to retrieve the Enum by Value

```
SalaryHeadMasterEnum.getEnumByString("Basic Pay")
```

Use Below code to get ENUM as String

```
SalaryHeadMasterEnum.BASIC_PAY.name()
```

Use below code to get string Value for enum

```
SalaryHeadMasterEnum.BASIC_PAY.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by thakre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70908450/642706) is correct. I will restate to more directly address the specifics of the question.

> every enum must have specific fields, such as price,

So define your enum with such a field.

```
enum Flavor {
    private BigDecimal price ;
}
```

Pass the value intended for that field to the constructor of each enum object.

```
enum Flavor {
    // Enum objects. 
    VANILLA( 2 ) , CHOCOLATE( 2 ) , LAVENDER( 4 )
    
    // Member fields.
    private int price ;

    // Constructor.
    public Flavor ( int price ) {
        this.price = price ;
    }
}
```

> I want to create a class to get this fields, what can I do in this situation?

No need for another class. Just add a getter method on the enum.

```
enum Flavor {
    // Enum objects. 
    VANILLA( 2 ) , CHOCOLATE( 2 ) , LAVENDER( 4 )
    
    // Member fields.
    private int price ;

    // Constructor.
    public Flavor ( int price ) {
        this.price = price ;
    }

    // Getters. 
    public int getPrice() { return this.price ; } 
}
```

Usage:

```
int extendedCost = quantity * Flavor.VANILLA.getPrice() ;
```